# How to create a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy Core?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Careful, I'm not asking for the widespread declarative mapping, but for the classical mapping. I haven't been able to find any examples nor anything in the documentation.

Because unlike delarative, you don't have a ORM in classical mapping. Hence I don't think I can use a `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`.

Any advice, please?

```
StudyTable = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "study",
    metadata,
    Column("id", String(100), primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String(100), nullable=False),
    Column("sponsor", String(100), nullable=False),
)

ParticipantTable = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "participant",
    metadata,
    Column("id", String(200), primary_key=True),
    Column("date_of_birth", DATE(), nullable=False),
)
```

Comment: Have you seen the [classical mappings docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings)?

Comment: Thanks yes. But I can't see Many to Many in there.  But I found this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html?highlight=mant%20many#many-to-many ,which is declarative. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

"[Classical Mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-a-k-a-classical-mappings)" (vs. "[Declarative Mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping)") is a feature of SQLAlchemy ORM. What you are describing is SQLAlchemy Core, and no, Core does not automatically handle many-to-many relationships. You need to implement those in your Core queries with joins between the association table and the parent tables.

Comment: Thanks, I see. And how will the solution look like? You mean creating a separate `association_table` with one foreign key to `Study` and one foreign key to `Participant`?

Comment: I would even dare to say that the concept of "relationship" does not exist in the Core (as it is understood to be in ORM). So what you have is just the concept of "foreign keys" between the tables, and relationships implied by those.

Comment: @Houman - Yes, although you need an association table (or an association *object*) for ORM as well.

Comment: Thanks, I provided a solution based on your suggestions. Please let me know if that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In spirit of Stackoverflow to provide a workable solution, I have written this based on the suggestions provided. Please let me know if I have missed anything.

```
association_table = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "study_participant",
    metadata,
    Column("study_id", String(100), ForeignKey("study.id"), nullable=False, index=True),
    Column("participant_id", String(100), ForeignKey("participant.id"), nullable=False, index=True),
)
```

**Usage**

I have to insert a `participant` and `study` first before I can create the association in this table.

If I wanted to see in which studies a participant has participated:

```
query = association_table.select().where(
            association_table.c.participant_id == "p1"
)
profiles = await db.fetch_all(query)
```

This will return the links to all studies for the given participant id.